# How can I configured jaas.conf in order to Kafka Inbound Endpoint WSO2 EI 6.6.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, apache-zookeeper, jaas

I have WSO2 EI 6.6.0 and I am using the next libs to configure Kafka Inbound Enpoint.

dropins:

```
org.apache.synapse.kafka.poll-1.0.10.jar
```

lib:

```
 kafka_2.12-1.0.0.jar
 kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar 
 metrics-core-2.2.0.jar 
 scala-library-2.12.3.jar 
 zkclient-0.10.jar 
 zookeeper-3.4.10.jar
```

Then I configured the jaas.conf file like I saw in this tutorial: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Kafka+Inbound+Protocol+, it is to say that I created the folders /conf/identity inside repository folder of WSO2.

Now the content of my file jaas is the next:

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username=""
        password=""
};

KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username=""
    password="";
};
```

I have this information:

```
IP: X.X.X.X
Port: X
topic: X
user:
password:
security.protocol: SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
```

To finish, I have a inbound endpoint in EI:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="kafka" sequence="request" onError="fault" class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer" suspend="false">
   <parameters>
      <parameter name="interval">10</parameter>
      <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="inbound.behavior">polling</parameter>
      <parameter name="value.deserializer">org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer</parameter>
      <parameter name="topic.name">test</parameter>
      <parameter name="poll.timeout">100</parameter>
      <parameter name="bootstrap.servers">localhost:9093</parameter>
      <parameter name="group.id">hello</parameter>
      <parameter name="contentType">application/json</parameter>
      <parameter name="key.deserializer">org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer</parameter>
      <parameter name="security.protocol">SASL_SSL</parameter>
      <parameter name="sasl.mechanism">PLAIN</parameter>
   </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

The problem is that I receive the next error:

```
[2022-04-21 15:19:10,098]  INFO {org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig} - ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9093]
        check.crcs = true
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.auto.commit = true
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = prueba-kafka
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 50
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 305000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
        security.protocol = SASL_SSL
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

[2022-04-21 15:19:10,119] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter} - Error in executing task: Failed to construct kafka consumer org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer.poll(KafkaMessageConsumer.java:351)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.generic.GenericTask.taskExecute(GenericTask.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.common.InboundTask.execute(InboundTask.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:98)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:781)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:635)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:617)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.kafka.KafkaMessageConsumer.poll(KafkaMessageConsumer.java:333)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Error de configuraci├│n:
        L├¡nea 6: se esperaba [option key]
        at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:137)
        at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile.<init>(ConfigFile.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:255)
        at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration$2.run(Configuration.java:247)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.getConfiguration(Configuration.java:246)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:112)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:78)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:103)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:86)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
        ... 13 more
```

I see that the variable: sasl.jaas.config is null but I have configured de jaas file. How can I add this variable value?

I have tried to add in the inbound endpoint and work fine but the jaas file it is not using in any moment.

How can I configured the jaas file to add this propertie?

Thank you